# How to get product id in admin product edit page when using component grid

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, magento2.4

I am trying to get request param `id` when editing the page in my component dataprovider file.
But getting always null value in it.

I am rendering a grid in the product edit page and I need to filter my data based on the current edit page. and when I try to click on the tab it fires the `mui/index/render` action and does not get product id in it.

I have also tried using this code `(int)$this->request->getParam('current_product_id');` but it is also returning an empty value.
can anyone please guide me on this?

even in the registry not available.

Here is the dataSource tag from my ui component file

```
<dataSource name="pricelist_listing_data_source">
    <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
        <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Test\PriceLevel\Ui\DataProvider\Product\PricelistDataProvider</argument>
        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">pricelist_listing_data_source</argument>
        <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">entity_id</argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="cacheRequests" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </argument>
</dataSource>
```

Comment: Just print request params and check `print_r($this->request->getParams())`

Comment: @NalinSavaliya it was working fine before 2.3 but not working in 2.4 and there isny't any edit ID in `params`

Comment: could you please share XML code of your listing component?

Comment: @Max edited question and shared datasource node from ui component

Answer (score 0):

> **Try this code. Add your filter_url_params**

```
.......................................................................................
.......................................................................................

<dataSource name="abandoned_cart_email_schedule_listing_data_source">
    <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
        <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">AbandonedCartEmailScheduleFilterPool</argument>
        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">abandoned_cart_email_schedule_listing_data_source</argument>
        <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">scheduler_id</argument>
        <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">scheduler_id</argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">scheduler_id</item>
                </item>
                <item name="filter_url_params" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="row_id" xsi:type="string">*</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </argument>
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</dataSource>

.......................................................................................
.......................................................................................
```

Comment: already tried this way.but nothing happen